# Why won't this function return the Dynamic Image mutated?

Tags: image, for-loop, if-statement, image-processing, rust

I have a function which is supposed to check command line arguments and according to what the input is mutate the image. I know how to mutate the image outside of the scope of the for loop but it doesn't return the mutated image object.

I'm having trouble mutating the object and returning it, and I'm too inexperienced to understand how I should overcome this issue.

```
fn commands(args: Vec<String>, img1: &DynamicImage) -> DynamicImage {
        let length = args.len();
        
        let img2 = img1.clone();
       
        for n in 2..length{
                if &args[n] == "90"{
                        img2.rotate90();
                        return img2
                }else if &args[n] == "180"{
                        img2.rotate180(); 
                        return img2      
                }else if &args[n] == "270"{
                        img2.rotate270();
                        return img2
                }else{
                        eprintln!("Invalid input")
                }
                return img2
        }
        return img2
}
```

Comment: [Last time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74805598/why-cant-i-mutate-and-return-the-dynamicimage-object-in-rust) you asked a question on this @E_net4 posted a [working solution](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=07c7029e18db3dedba261067adc3e30d). Any issues with that?

Comment: @Caesar It didn't work... I thought it did cause no error showed up but no, I called it too soon and I was still stuck. I'm kinda upset cause I rewrote everything and ended up with the same issue.

Comment: @Caesar My lack of experience is my worst enemy, once this works I'm probably going to reference it for my future projects because when I code I draw upon things I worked on in the past to help me learn a language. I remember encountering an issue similar to this in c++ trying to add characters into a string and separate them and stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return the original, not the rotated image. One way I can tell at a glance is that `img2` is not mutable so it is unlikely you are modifying the current image. Upon checking the [documentation](https://docs.rs/image/latest/image/enum.DynamicImage.html#method.rotate90), it does indeed return a new image.

Here is one way you could rewrite it that would do this:

```rust
fn commands(args: Vec<String>, img: &DynamicImage) -> DynamicImage {
    for arg in &args[2..] {
        match arg.as_ref() {
            "90" => return img.rotate90(),
            "180" => return img.rotate180(),
            "270" => return img.rotate270(),
            _ => eprintln!("Invalid input"),
        }
    }

    img.clone()
}
```

You may want to consider returning an `Option<DynamicImage>` or `Result<DynamicImage, InvalidDegreesError>` (where `InvalidDegreesError` is some custom error type) instead to improve the functionality. Also, if the `args` field represents command line arguments, then you may want to consider using a crate like [`clap`](https://crates.io/crates/clap) to handle input verification.

Comment: Maybe you need to clone before rotating.

Comment: I didn't even know clap existed tbh, ty, I'm use your code as a building block and modify it to see if it works in my situation, I'll reply when/if it works and give you the checkmark.

Comment: @Locke 
It worked, I was using img.clone() at the beginning instead of the end so it didn't return the cloned image, I'll git commit this time travel and show you my incorrect work if you like, but thank you, now I think I understand better how to use clone function.

I was stuck on this for days and because of you I can not only progress further in developing my program but you also saved me lots of time telling me that clap existed.

I think i'ma end up restarting anyway but I truly appreciate your guidance.